# How are library specific errors thrown?

Tags: python

As I use new libraries, I notice that I can do something like

```
try:
    # all code not shown...
    socket.connect(())
except socket.error:
    print "found an error!"
```

In the example above, it is for the socket lib. How would I go about doing the same thing but for my own libraries?

So in my class, I'd like to be able to

```
def checkLen(self):

    if self.len > 1000:
        raise MyErrors.LEN_TOO_LONG

    return self.len
```

and in the caller...

```
try:
    object.checkLen()
except MyErrors.LEN_TOO_LONG:
    print "error found, the length was too long!"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By deriving from `BaseException` or an appropriate child.

```
class LenTooLongError(ValueError):
  pass
```

Comment: So I have to create a new class for each type of error I want?

Comment: Each exception type is a discrete exception type.

Comment: Interesting... Then I should sub class Error, and then create classes that subclass that but with appropriate names?

Comment: Unless your exceptions are vastly different from any of the built-in exceptions, you should derive from those as much as possible.